# I would like others to explain suitable questions to me

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-faq

In [The Class/Object Paradox confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675774/the-class-object-paradox-confusion) , the OP asks

> In the book The Well Grounded Rubyist (excerpt), David Black talks
>   about the "Class/Object Chicken-and-Egg Paradox". I'm having a tough
>   time understanding the entire concept.
>
> Can someone explain it in better/easier/analogical/other terms?
>
> Quote (emphasis mine):
>
> [block quotation of Ruby object's model the OP doesn't understand]

with no more attempt to make it specific, such as "so this means that ___ is true, right?"

At first I thought "that's too vague", but I looked at the FAQ, and it said

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about `______`”, then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain `______` to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
>   course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Should the FAQ be reworded to replace "explain" with something else? Or should the rest of the FAQ be sufficient to discourage overly vague questions?

Comment: The FAQ says, "you are probably OK," which means it is not always OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I think the "explain" test is appropriate. The questions still have to be *specific* and *answerable*.

I've voted to close "please explain [general topic]" questions as NC (if they were subjective) or NARQ (if they were just vague / too broad), but I think that *particular* question asks something specific, and is a real, constructive question.

He pulls out a reasonable length excerpt, and highlights the specific part he doesn't understand. He was responsive to comments. There are two on-point answers, either of which could fill in whatever the gap is in the OP's understanding. There is the potential for a complete answer that definitively describes the relationship between objects and classes in Ruby.

Another question does occur to me -- is the question conceptual enough to be on-topic at Programmers? I think it is. Does it need to be migrated? No, I think it's concrete enough for Stack Overflow.

If that question is closed, I'll vote to re-open.